# EXT:fluidcontent does not accept element configuration

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, fedext

I have already used Fluid ContentElements with FED and Flux and wanted to try to port my existing elements to TYPO3 6.1.5.

I've read up on the recent changes with FED and thus installed EXT:flux and EXT:fluidcontent as advised on the project homepage.

After none of my old FCEs worked out-of-the-box, I tried to create a very simple element containing only a text input field as a proof-of-concept and to learn the new ways of the FCEs.

Here's my code:

(TypoScript and HTML adapted from [Typo3 V6: How to create a content element container? (without TV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156751/typo3-v6-how-to-create-a-content-element-container-without-tv/15370609#15370609))

**TypoScript**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:css_styled_content/static/setup.txt">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:fluidcontent/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">

plugin.tx_fed {
    fce.myext {
        templateRootPath = EXT:myext/res/{$global.project_path}/assets/html/fluidCE/Templates/
    }
}
```

**HTML-Template in EXT:myext/res/{$global.project_path}/assets/html/fluidCE/Templates/**

```
{namespace flux=Tx_Flux_ViewHelpers}

<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
 xmlns:flux="http://fedext.net/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
 xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">

<f:layout name="Content" />

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:flexform id="textfoo" label="TextFoo">
        <flux:flexform.field.input name="textfoo" label="textfoo" />
    </flux:flexform>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">
    <h2>{textfoo}</h2>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
    <h1>{textfoo}</h1>
</f:section>

</div>
```

What I'm getting now in my Content-Element is the following:

[FluidCE Backend Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t27FI.png)

So my questions are the following:

- **Why is my text input field missing?**
- **Where does the "Title" field come from?**

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Best regards,
Grigori

**EDIT:** I have now enabled Flux Debug and get the following messages:

```
Flux Debug
Flux View Tx_Flux_MVC_View_ExposedTemplateView is able to read stored configuration from file /Users/username/workspace/projectname/typo3conf/ext/myext/res/projectname/assets/html/fluidCE/Templates/TextFoo.html

Flux Debug
The template file "" was not found. (1366824347)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after an IRC-session in #typo3@chat.freenode.net the guys (kudos to @cedricziel and @amkoroew) and I figured out that first of all the TER-versions of `EXT:flux` and `EXT:fluidcontent` are not working, but those from GitHub are:

- https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux
- https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent

The path to the template files needs to abide the default extbase convention, i.e. `EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/myFCE.html`

(There is a way to use a non-standard path, but I haven't tried it)

`EXT:fluidcontent` also expects the TypoScript-setup to be as follows:

```
plugin {
    tx_myext {
        view {
            label = Fluid Content Elements
            extensionKey = myext
            templateRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates
        }
    }
}
```

After updating the extensions and moving the file to its new location, the FCE works as expected.